# OpenGL - Adding new data to texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a spectogram efficently. Currently I am doing everything on CPU using a texture buffer by looping through the whole texture buffer and pushing the new data to the "queue". However, this costs me alot of CPU time. I want to add new column of pixel data to the texture, move old data to right, so the new data appear on left side while the old data moves to right. This will create a waterfall/sidescrolling effect if I do it each frame.

I am using `glTexSubImage2D()` to add new data, but this will not advance old data to right. How can I achieve this by using OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need to move any data around. Simply treat the texture as circular in the horizontal direction, basically a circular buffer of columns. Then take scare of the scrolling during rendering by choosing the texture coordinates accordingly.

Say you want to display `n` columns at a time. Create a texture of width `n`, and in each step `k` store the data in column `k % n` of the texture:

```
glTexSubImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, k % n, 0, 1, height, ...);
```

Then use texture coordinates in the range `1 + (k % n) / n` to `(k % n) / n` in the horizontal direction, with the texture wrap mode set to `GL_REPEAT`. Or pass an offset to your shader, and add it to the texture coordinates in the GLSL code.

And of course, if you have all data ahead of time, and it's not very large, you can simply store all of it in a texture right from the start, and scroll through it by shifting the texture coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this the way you say you want to do this, it will be expensive. You will need to copy the data from the texture back onto the cpu (or keep a copy on the cpu), and then add your data onto it there, then use `glTexSubImage2D` to copy the **whole** new image back again.

An alternative if you already know all the data is to place it all in the texture, then slowly move the texture to the right. If you need to you could make a black square to cover parts of the texture you don't want visible.

You could also go in between and create multiple textures, a new one each time you get enough data, and move them in succession.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by the fragment shader (or pixel shader).This shader is executed by the GPU of your system.There are different shading languages are available.one from the nVidia( cg Shader ) and others are GLSL or HLSL provided by the Microsoft. With shaders its possible( They are used for this kind of purposes).
And definitely your CPU time will be reduced because its executed by the GPU.